# How do we disable Test Case work item type in Azure DevOps

Tags: devops, testcase, disable

We have a requirement where users should not create any work item except Bug. Able to disable the other work item types except Test Case.

How do we disable Test Case or restrict users from creating a Test Case or convert type to bug.

Answer (score 2):

By default Disable option is not available for work items Testcase ,Test Plan, Test Suite in Azure Devops . We can only edit the work item template by using inherit process.